# Spin Edit to display specific values

Tags: properties, devexpress

I have a spin edit from Devexpress and what I would like to do with it is set its value to only display a year month value, with the format or YYYYMM. I have code to do that but I was wondering if it is possible to do this with the properties of the spin edit. The problem I encounter is that when it gets to 201212 and you increment it should go to 201301, but of cause it just goes to 201213. The same happens in revers from 201301 to 201299. I'll give the sample code just so that you can see how it is meant to work but again I want to know if this can be done using just the properties of the spinEdit.

```
    private void spDate_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        spDate.Properties.EditValueChangedFiringMode = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.EditValueChangedFiringMode.Default;
        int year = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(spDate.Value / 100));
        int month = Convert.ToInt32(spDate.Value - (year * 100));

        if (month > 12) { month = 1; year += 1; }
        if (month < 1) { month = 12; year -= 1; }

        spDate.Value = (year * 100) + (month);
    }
```

obviously that first line is manually set with the properties otherwise its a little buggy but I added it in there so you can see what property to set beforehand.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I Think that you have to use editors masks. What you are trying to display is obviously a date. Try to have a look [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument583).

Comment: it is a date but in this format yyyyMM as far as I can see is it sortof works however it doesn't check for valid month values and removes the current displayed value. I can't see what I am entering when I click the up arrow and I can go to 201313, which isn't right. I need that check as well as the mask.